# Problem creating directories in tempfile.TemporaryDirectory

Tags: python, temporary-files, temporary-directory

i am having trouble with tempfile library. As part of a bigger code, i need to open a temporary folder (that needs to be closed at the end). i will dump some files in it. however i need to organize what's inside, so I would need to open a directory inside this temporary folder. I tried with mkdir and makedirs, and before the temporary folder gets deleted i zip everything to check if the directories I created were actually there. apparently not, at the end I get an empty zip file.
what is wrong here, why are the directories dir1 and dir2 not created?

```
import os
import tempfile
import zipfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as directory:
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(directory, "dir1"))
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(directory, "dir2"))
    finally:
        # zip to check the content created
        def zipdir(path, ziph):
            # ziph is zipfile handle
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                for file in files:
                    ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))

        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile("final.zip", 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zipdir(directory, zipf)
        zipf.close()
```

Comment: Try using except: in your try: block to see if either os.mkdir or os.mkdirs is failing

Comment: good idea, i tried except, there is no error...

Comment: i also tried time.sleep  to have enough time to check it in the temp folder manually . the folders are created. why do they disappear later?

Comment: They disappear because they're supposed to. That's how TemporaryDirectory works!

Comment: but i need to fish for some specific files created in these dir1 dir2 directories. that is why i am asking why do they disappear . i zipped the whole structure before the temp directory is deleted

Comment: i think i found the problem if i copy a file in dir1 the final zip won't be empty. it's like the function cannot copy empty folders